# VS2013: Hitting a breakpoint brings my computer to a crawl

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints

My project is a fairly CPU intensive program (a ray tracer) which chugs along just fine until I want to debug. Whenever I hit a break in my program, either through a breakpoint or __debugbreak(), my entire computer slows to a crawl. Everything - mouse input, keyboard input, other programs, ctrl+alt+del, everything lags for over ten seconds or more (I can't tell if it gets worse the longer I'm 'debugging'). Usually it's faster to just pull the plug on my PC and reboot instead of waiting for the game of 'press alt+F4', 'wait for the dialog...', 'press enter', 'wait for VS to close...' (Yes, seriously, it's faster to reboot than do that).

Because of this, my only method of debugging has been putting print statements places. Help!

Anyone? :(

Comment: Incorrect thread priority?

Comment: I just have the one thread from main() - how would I check what the thread priority was, and what would an incorrect value be?

Comment: Figured out how to check, the thread priority is THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL

Comment: Maybe conditional breakpoints? I know that slows down the debugger, but never noticed it slowing down the whole PC.

Comment: That doesn't help either. While the program is running everything is fine, but once any breakpoint hits, the computer slows to a crawl.

Comment: I bet it's your antivirus software. Try disabling that....

Comment: Is "intellitrace" recording and saving huge amounts of data?

Comment: Start taskmgr before, set it to high prio and always in foreground, then keep an eye on which process consumes CPU.

Comment: I set task manager to realtime priority and watched what was going on - disc and cpu were close to 0% and memory stayed constant around ~30%, so nothing much there.

Comment: How would I tell if intellitrace was doing anything?

Comment: I tried disabling Windows Defender and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may have either the threads window open or "show threads in source" feature turned on (or both). These features cause significant delays when entering break state. If either or both of those conditions are true, closing the threads window and disabling the "show threads in source" feature will make hitting breakpoints orders of magnitude faster.